# How is it possible for django to go through DoesNotExist and then raise "Duplicate entry"?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-users

I received the following django error

```
File "./project/auth_backend.py", line 31, in authenticate
user.save()
...
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'user_name' for key 'username'")
```

The said file contains the following code (which is based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    user = User(username=username, password=password)
...
user.save()
```

It seems that somehow it raised User.DoesNotExist even when it actually does exist. My database is MySQL.

I've seen others with a similar problem but unlike them, I'm not using any database caching.

Comment: Did you try creating a `User` via the documented `create_user` method? `user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')` :: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Comment: This problem occurs always or only sometimes? Please show all `authenticate` function.

Comment: @hybrid I haven't tried it yet. How different will it be from my current code? Note that in this example, I don't think it should have raised User.DoesNotExist in the first place which means that if it behaves correctly, it would not reach the user creation part.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup It happened once and I can't replicate it now. My authenticate function is mostly the same as the custom authentication example from django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like this. It was due to a inconsistency in my database. The `_seq` was out of date in the database. To fix this, try using the `sqlsequencereset` function in your manage.py. It prints all the commands which you should execute on your database...
See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset-app-label-app-label) for more information.